# Dell R630 supported PCIe to NVMe (m.2) adapter and drive?

Tags: dell-poweredge, ssd, pci-express, nvme

I can't seem to find any information anywhere about supported PCIe to NVMe (m.2) adapter and a brand of drive that will also work.
I am aware third party adapters and drives tend to work with various OSs (ESXi) but are not compatible and cause the fans to ramp up (something I am looking to avoid).

I do know that NVMe drives can be put in the 2.5" drive bays, but are heavily bottle-necked by the SATA interface. For this reason I am after the speed that a PCIe adapter can offer.

I do know that the tower servers Dell offers have supported PCIe adapters, for example the Dell Ultra-Speed Drive Quad NVMe M.2 PCIe Card.

Does this drive simply being Dell OEM make it compatible with the R630?
Does the brand of NVMe drive matter if the adapter itself is compatible, or do both the adapter and drive have to be Dell compatible?

Comment: Just a tiny thing I've faced with a third party adapters - I was not able to passthrough all NVMe drives to a VM under ESXi 7.0. Was facing an error. No errors on ESX 6.7

Answer (score 3):

> Does this drive simply being Dell OEM make it compatible with the R630?

Yes. But so too is nearly any NVMe drive and adapter. Causing the fans to ramp up isn't a problem with the NVMe adapter per se, it's the R630 seeing the [addition of *any* PCIe card causing the fan speeds to ramp up](https://www.dell.com/community/PowerEdge-Hardware-General/Loud-fan-noise/td-p/5058223). Suggested resolutions include updating the Lifecycle Controller firmware or making a trip to the *Processor Power Management* settings.

> Does the brand of NVMe drive matter if the adapter itself is compatible?

It might matter, there's a LOT of brands. Most any should work. Since this is a server, odds are you want a brand that has a track record of performing dependably under server workloads for a long time. Anything that matches that criteria is going to work in your R630.

Also, [you can't boot an R630 off an NVMe disk unless you spec the server with the 4-disk NVMe backplane](https://www.dell.com/community/Rack-Servers/Unable-to-boot-from-PCIE-NvMe-device-What-does-quot-unavailable/m-p/7520923/highlight/false#M6176). Workarounds include putting the boot loader on the SD vCard, the Internal Dual SD module (IDSDM), or any SATA/SAS disk. After the initial boot sequence, the boot loader can hand off to the OS on the NVMe.

Comment: I was under the assumption that 3rd party "unsupported" PCIe cards caused the fans to ramp up because they don't have readable temperature sensors, thus the fans are set high to provide enough airflow to the card?

Comment: That might be, but I haven't seen Dell tell us that. I assumed it's because adding PCI cards adds airflow resistance. When we do that, then it's on us to monitor the temp sensors and adjust the power profile accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a few years late to the party, but I just purchased a [Crucial P5 M.2 SSD](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B087QRVVVH)  and an [Icy Dock" M.2->U.2 adapter](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07T8LJY23), and the R630 picked it up with no issues (*we shall see if I can convert it into my boot device*).

The only issue I've got right now is that it appears the SATA/SAS drive trays are not the same (*probably on purpose?*) as the 4 right-most bays on the 10-bay R630–the drive doesn't sit high enough in the bay to slip on to the adapter.

I've got a line out to the guys at [cloudninjas.com](http://cloudninjas.com) (that's where I got my PCIe kit) to see if there is a different tray I need or if I'm going to have to get out the drill.

So, I can say that for sure, the Crucial P5 M.2 is compatible with the R630 if you have the PCIe backplane and have it hooked up to the expansion card!

P.S. my fans are not running higher than usual. Thought I should also mention that.